# Step identification bug in script using Material Steppers

Tags: javascript

I am working on a small AngularJS application with with Material Steppers.

I have to select items from two sections of the page and return `true` *only if* the items from *both sections* belong to the category with id (`categoryID`) 1.

Choosing items from section A already changes the variable `this.isTriggerB`, that should only be change after choosing from section A:

```
class Controller {
  constructor($mdStepper) {

    this.isTriggerA = false;
    this.isTriggerB = false;
    this.clickedStepNumber = 0;

    getCurrentStep() {
      this.steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper');
      const steps = this.steppers.steps;
      steps.forEach((el, index) => {
        let step = this.steppers.steps[index];
        if (step.isClicked()) {
          this.clickedStepNumber = step.stepNumber;
        }
      });
    }

    checkCategory() {
      this.getCurrentStep();
      if (this.filter.provider) {
        let categoryID = parseInt(this.filter.category.id, 10);

        console.log('Cid: ' + categoryID);

        if (categoryID !== 1) {
          this.isTestPassed = false;
        } else {
          if (parseInt(this.clickedStepNumber, 10 === 1)) {
            this.isTriggerA = true;
            console.log('Step: ' + this.clickedStepNumber);
            console.log("A1: " + this.isTriggerA);
            console.log("B1: " + this.isTriggerB);
          }

          if (parseInt(this.clickedStepNumber, 10 === 2)) {
            this.isTriggerB = true;
            console.log('Step: ' + this.clickedStepNumber);
            console.log("A2: " + this.isTriggerA);
            console.log("B2: " + this.isTriggerB);
          }

          if (this.isTriggerA === true && this.isTriggerB === true) {
            this.isTestPassed = true;
          } else {
            this.isTestPassed = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The script should not even go inside if it is executing.
It should treat the 2 cases (steps) differently.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the banana:

```
    if (categoryID !== 1) {
      this.isTestPassed = false;
    } else {
      ̶i̶f̶ ̶(̶p̶a̶r̶s̶e̶I̶n̶t̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶e̶d̶S̶t̶e̶p̶N̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶,̶ ̶1̶0̶ ̶=̶=̶=̶ ̶1̶)̶)̶ ̶{̶
      if (parseInt(this.clickedStepNumber, 10) === 1) {
        this.isTriggerA = true;
        console.log('Step: ' + this.clickedStepNumber);
        console.log("A1: " + this.isTriggerA);
        console.log("B1: " + this.isTriggerB);
      }

      ̶i̶f̶ ̶(̶p̶a̶r̶s̶e̶I̶n̶t̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶e̶d̶S̶t̶e̶p̶N̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶,̶ ̶1̶0̶ ̶=̶=̶=̶ ̶2̶)̶)̶ ̶{̶
      if (parseInt(this.clickedStepNumber, 10) === 2) {
        this.isTriggerB= true;
        console.log('Step: ' + this.clickedStepNumber);
        console.log("A2: " + this.isTriggerA);
        console.log("B2: " + this.isTriggerB);
      }
```

Comment: I should've seen that miself. :)

Comment: There is this problem I could now see: the if in the second block (step) does not "remember" the value returned by the if in the first block. It returns to the value at the top of the constructor. How can I fix that?